# Google Place Autocomplete on Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, httprequest, google-places-api

I want to create an app that autocompletes a destination text box. I read this documentation about it:
[Adding Place Autocomplete to your Android App](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android)
However it says that you can't use your API key internally and that you must instead access an external web service to make the autocomplete submission and return the results to your app. I then came across this:
[Place Autocomplete in response to an HTTP request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete?hl=fr)
This states that you can make a request with your API key as part of the URL for the HTTP request. Can you do this internally from your app or would you have to submit that HTTP request from an external web service as well? If you can just make this HTTP request from within the app, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The first link does not state *you must* use private proxy to access Google Places API. It is recommended though since such a proxy is way more reliable place to store your API key than bundle it within the published application.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution:

1) Get an application's API key from the Google console.
[Create Api Key](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys)

2) Use this module from GitHub to make Google Place Auto Complete. It's easy to integrate: **[Android GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://github.com/karamsa/GooglePlaceAutoComplete)**